# How to assign a rabbitMQ Connection to a Property of a Class to use it in another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

So the main Idea is to make a Wrapper Class that holds Some functions to make it easier using rabbitmq publish, subscribe and RPC features. The goal is for example that if I want to publish something I'll easily use the publish function inside the Rabbit Wrapper class, for exp it ll look something like this: `var rabbit = new IRabbitMQ();` and then to publish I'll use the publisher function `rabbit.publisher(exchangeName, queueName, etc..)` and if I was interested in receiving then I'll call easily `rabbit.subscriber(exchangeName, queueName, etc..)`

I tried all the ideas that were in my head, it didnt work with nested classes because in js I didn't find a handy way to do that, I tried also factory function or a simple object and avoid using classes but it didnt work. The problem was always that when I make a connection and create a channel between me and rabbitMQ, that I couldnt store that connection and channel in a Property of the Wrapper class to use it in another function if I want to

```
 class IRabbitMQ {

constructor() {
   this.init(rabbitMQServer); // this should initialize my this.connection and this.channel property to the connection and channel object but instead receive an error because there are undefined
 }

async init(host) {
    try {
        const connection = await amqplib.connect(host);
        const channel = await connection.createChannel();
        channel.prefetch(1);
        console.log(' [x] Awaiting RPC requests');
        this.connection = connection; // this should make a property connection with the connection object, when i console.log here it shows me the connection object but if i want to use this in another function it gaves me undefined value!
        this.channel = channel;
    }catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

async publisher(queue, body) {

    let q = await this.channel.assertQueue(queue, {durable: false});

    this.channel.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)));

    console.log("msg sent ", body);
}

async subsriber(queue) {

    let q = await this.channel.assertQueue(queue, {durable: false});
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);

    await  this.channel.consume(q, function(msg) {
        console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
      }, {noAck: true});
}


}

   // another example using a simple object instead of a class
      /* var IRabbitMQ = {

channel : undefined, 

init : async (host) => {

    try {
        const connection = await amqplib.connect(host);
        const channel = await connection.createChannel();
        channel.prefetch(1);
        console.log(' [x] Awaiting RPC requests');
        this.channel = channel;

    }catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
},

publisher : async (queue, body) =>{
    this.init(rabbitMQServer);
    let q = await this.channel.assertQueue(queue, {durable: false});

    this.channel.sendToQueue(q, Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)));

    console.log("msg sent ", body);
},

subscriber : async(queue) => {
    this.init(rabbitMQServer);
    let q = await this.channel.assertQueue(queue, {durable: false});
    console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);

    await  this.channel.consume(q, function(msg) {
        console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
      }, {noAck: true});
}

   } */
```

Expected output is that I can have access to the value of connection and channel to use it later in another functions because if not than it ll not make sense to make a Wrapper class. if you guys have also a better Idea from your Experience of making this that would be helpful to hear.

Comment: `expected output` from where? I can't see you instantiating that class, nor using it in the code you posted ... you're probably *doing something wrong™* - and what do you get instead?

Comment: if I create an Instance from this class so for exp: var r = new IRabbitMQ(); then r.connection should not be undefined but instead i get undefined

Comment: ok let's say i make an instance and i want to publish something, then i ll make var r = new IRabbitMQ(); and then i ll call r.publisher() but here i get an error : Cannot read property 'assertQueue' of undefined

Comment: r.connection won't be defined until `init` finishes - which it won't immediately, being asynchronous

Comment: Ok i thought about it but i tried to use synchronous with RabbitMQ because it ll give also an Error. I tried that too and it gives an error that connection.createChannel() is not a function

Comment: try something like https://pastebin.com/3p4Jn7JJ

Comment: thank you for that, but do you think this will work in my case ? my goal is actually to make it abstracter to use rabbitmq in a big Project, i mean i need to make all the functions wrapped in a big Class and from that class if i make an instance then an instance of a connection or rather channel ll be done as well and then i can call the publish or subscribe functions from it

Comment: i thank you a lot but i think it would make my Project or rather class more complicated to do it your way. it would be also hard to maintain if it went bigger and i wanted to change something in the Future. I'm open for Ideas if you have one ;)

Comment: `your way` - well, actually, that's **your** way, with just the smallest change needed to make **your** code work

Comment: can you maybe suggest me another way ? :)

Comment: Not without a understanding your needs in entirety - and, well, that's kind of beyond what stack overflow is about

Comment: but I explained what i exactly want to do. I think also that everyone who worked with Rabbitmq before, had the Idea of making a big class where all Functions and Events in Rabbitmq are encapsulated in it. i wanted to make the same thing and i thought it's a good Idea to ask for Help here since there is many experienced People

Comment: yes, you did explain everything, I didn't understand it correctly

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean that ironically, i hope you don't, I tried to explain what i want to do, if you want i can explain again.., you already helped me with that example and I thank you

Comment: no, I'm serious ... I can't help any more than I have (which wasn't helpful for what you want)

Comment: delete that `this.init()` call from inside your `constructor` and call the init after you are instantiating your class, it may work. example:  `var r = new IRabbitMQ();  await r.init(args);`